# Changing if a HWND Is topmost in run time

Tags: c++, winapi

So I have a question.

how can I make it so my HWND window is topmost on a toggle?

Would It be something like

```
    HWND Flags = HWND_TOPMOST;
    SetWindowPos(LOADER_HWND, Flags, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

    //
    if (toggle) Flags = HWND_NOTOPMOST;
    else Flags = HWND_TOPMOST;
```

I've tried something like this and it did not make the program top most, am I doing something wrong by not updating the window?

Comment: Does "not work" mean "it doesn't become topmost"? Also are you using windows API?

Comment: Yes I'm using the windows API; Sorry for saying "not work" its a really bad habit that I'm trying to break, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Are you sure `LOADER_HWND` has the correct value?

Comment: Yes the window displays. This all works, its just the part from making the topmost toggle.

Comment: You are setting the flags *after* calling SetWindowPos, which yeah not going to help much. Also does SetWindowPos really support topmost as a flag? That sounds.. unlikely

Comment: @Voo I presumed so. How can I set the flags for SetWindowPos? EDIT: It does support top most flag.

Comment: Required reading _"How do I create a topmost window that is never covered by other topmost windows?"_ https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253

Comment: @RichardCritten I've stated before I have the topmost working, its just the toggle.

Comment: I can switch the top state of HWND at runtime, have you checked whether `SetWindowPos` is executed successfully, or you can show [a minimal, reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) without private information that we can find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I was not updating the window.

Answer (score 0):

> To use SetWindowPos to bring a window to the top, the process that owns the window must have SetForegroundWindow permission

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos

i think it's about that